# What does mean "failed to deter" in this phrase?

Tags: meaning

As I found in the dictionaries, "fail to deter" means something/somebody can't prevent to turn aside, discourage or prevent from acting another thing. So, the meaning of this sentence is not clear for me:

> Yet the lack of public demand and prohibitive cost failed to deter the cash-strapped Warner Bros, which released *The Jazz Singer* with a Vitaphone disc soundtrack in October 1927.

In my understanding, when we use "fail to deter", we want to say something tried to do a thing but couldn't. Here, *the lack of public demand* and *prohibitive cost* don't deter *cash-strapped*, contrary, they cause it.

Comment: They're not deterring *cash-strapped*, they're not deterring Warner Brothers.  *Cash-strapped* is just an adjective describing Warner Brothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the cash-strapped Warner Bros

Warner Bros had financial difficulties.

> the lack of public demand and prohibitive cost

Both factors are unfavourable for film production. It's costly and no-one is going to watch it.

> failed to deter *[the company from producing another movie]*

In simple terms, it means "failed to stop", "couldn't prevent".

> Yet all these unfavourable factors failed to stop Warner Bros from releasing The Jazz Singer.